# Clarity regarding performing unit test in Spring Boot Application

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I got off from writing basic unit tests using JUnit for simple methods that adds two numbers. I can verify the result by using the assert* family of function calls. Now I want to unit test a Spring Boot controller.

Here is the example of the unit test class -

```
public class MyJunitTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Mock
private MyService service;

@InjectMocks
private MyController controller;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void unitTestGetAssessmentDetails() {
    when(service.getTest(Someobject.class)).thenReturn(customObjectWithValues);
    Results results = controller.getCall(someRequestObject);
    assertEquals(results, someOtherObjectPrefilledWithValues);
}
}
```

My question is, if I know the values set in `customObjectWithValues`, then `someOtherObjectPrefilledWithValues` is also set by me, then assertEquals will always give a pass to the test, right? It's essentially testing if 1==1 kind of test. So what is the point of doing these unit tests? I know that the service object should not connect to the actual DB, and hence we are mocking it. So what is the point of doing these tests? Am I missing the bigger picture here as to how to view unit tests?

P.S. - Please feel free to remove this question if it violates the rules of this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test verifies that `getCall` returns the expected results;
this is a black box test.
Since you are writing a unit test,
this is only sufficient to "pretend" to perform a unit test.
This technique is common in firms that conflate code quality with
unit test code coverage.

A better technique is to identify the steps that will be taken by the controller class and to verify that each was executed (perhaps in the correct order, as well).

I will assume that `MyController.getCall` looks something like this:

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;

public BlammyReturnValueType getCall(final BlammyRequestType request)
{
    final BlammyReturnValueType returnValue;

    returnValue = myService.someServiceMethod(request);

    return returnValue;
}
```

In this case,
I would add the following to the `unitTestGetAssessmentDetails` test method:

```java
... The current stuff including the assert.

Mockito.verify(service, times(1)).someServiceMethod(customObjectWithValues);
```

This will confirm that the service method was called exactly one time,
which is correct in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, unit testing is more about testing the logic written in your function/controller/service. Now, your function might be very simple or it might be very complex. For ex, your function might be taking and UserId in request, connect to database, gets the data and return it and since you are mocking the database connection, you might feel like if you are passing the mocked object as database response, you will obviously get the same response, so what's the point of testing. It might seem correct to not test at all in this case. But let me give you another example, say you have a very complex function, which takes some UserId, gets the whole year data of users banking history, cumulates it and calculates the amount user earned for this year. Now, think how complex this function is. Now since you have mocked the DB connection you will pass in some data, a lot of computation goes on inside and gives the user an amount earned as Interest on saving. Now, for a given mocked data, you know the answer should come as some X amount. Now, over the time, someone made a mistake (maybe subtracted something which was needed to be added). Now, when you run the test. This test will fail and you know something is wrong with logic. Not here you are not directly expecting the output to be equal to your mocked data, some computation has been done over the data, so to verify after each change that function logic is correct, you need to write a unit test to verify it. Now if you see here, your are not testing 1==1 but something different. This is why people write unit tests, to check their logic inside a unit of code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we have 3 layers which are Controller, Service, Repository (DAO if you prefer).  I usually do not test controllers because I do not put any logic in them, I just define the endpoint and call the service.  The service is what I heavily unit test so you would inject the mocks into your service.  Then you would mock your Repository so it wouldn't try to connect to a database.

```
@InjectMocks
private MyService service;

@Mock
private MyRepository myrepo

@Test
public void unitTestGetAssessmentDetails() {
    when(myrepo.find(someInt)).thenReturn(customObjectWithValues);
    Results results = service.serviceMethod(someRequestObject);
    assertEquals(results, someOtherObjectPrefilledWithValues);
}
```

Since controllers are supposed to have no logic they shouldn't need unit test because as you correctly say it's a 1==1 test.  But they would be tested by integration tests